# PI-OS 11 (Debian Bulleye ) NFS hangup during mount

Tags: debian, nfs

I have a (for me very surprising problem ) with NFS on a Raspi 4 running Debian 11:

```
sudo mount -t nfs server:/Public /home/user/Public
```

If I execute the command, it's simply stuck and never comes back. The exactly same HW with Debian 10 is working fine. And in addition I have a Intel based Linux machine running Debian 11 without any problems.
The hangup occurs the same if I put the mount statement into /etc/fstab, then mount -a locks up.
No error messages in syslog oder systems journal. The OS is of course up to date.
Are there any ideas what could be wrong ? Beside I'm using only the client, no server components. And the server is a QNAP NAS, also latest version. And as I said, the NFS shares work with every other OS.
Thanks in advance
Regardas
Thomas